# Prevent Brave Browser from asking for confirmation to open external application every time

Tags: browser, protocol, brave, protocol-handler

Need to disable Brave Browser to ask for confirmation to open external application every time. Every time I click a phone number, in my use case for example, I get this popup again.

[image]

The solution used to be to edit registry, as this was previously working until yesterday:

Policies > BraveSoftware > Brave >

```
Add DWORD > ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox 1
```

Policies > BraveSoftware > Brave > URLWhitelist >

```
Add String > 1 tel://*
Add String > 2 telnet://*
Add String > 3 tel:*
Add String > 4 telnet:*
```

[image]

Brave broke this solution with a recent update so that now it's broken and asks every time again. How can I do it now so that every single time I am not asked to click again?

--

Update 02-17-2021:

IT'S UNBELIEVABLE THAT THIS HAS NOT BEEN SOLVED! I want to use TimeDoctor, but there is no Firefox extension. Thus I cannot use TimeDoctor since THERE IS NO WAY I AM CLICKING TWICE FOR EVERY DIAL 200+ TIMES PER DAY!!

Therfore, STILL HAVE ABANDONED BRAVE AND CHROME BROWSER, FORCED TO USE FIREFOX.

Comment: For now, I've abandoned all Chromium-based browsers for work because Firefox does not have this problem, until this problem is solved.

Comment: IT'S UNBELIEVABLE THAT THIS HAS NOT BEEN SOLVED! I want to use TimeDoctor, but there is no Firefox extension. Thus I cannot use TimeDoctor since THERE IS NO WAY I AM CLICKING TWICE FOR EVERY DIAL 200+ TIMES PER DAY!!

Therefore, STILL HAVE ABANDONED BRAVE AND CHROME BROWSER, FORCED TO USE FIREFOX.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to create a JSON document for the protocol that opens an external application.  In Linux, this is done with files located in **/etc/brave/policies/managed**.  For example, to whitelist **tel** you'd create **/etc/brave/policies/managed/tel.json** and it should contain the following:

```
{
  "AutoLaunchProtocolsFromOrigins": [
    {
      "allowed_origins": [ "*" ],
      "protocol": "tel"
    }
  ]
}
```

Each protocol gets its own file, and you have to restart Brave for this to take effect.  You can check to see if the change was applied by going to brave://policy in your browser.

For Windows, it's similar, but you put the JSON in a registry key instead of using files.  For more details, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension/issues/68).

Comment: Chrome stores the policies at `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed` (notice the `opt` part), no wonder that I couldn't get brave to register new policies. Thanks a million!

Comment: Chrome and its derivatives all have slightly different paths for this.  I described a solution for Brave, but very similar solutions can be adapted to other Chromium-based browsers.  A little investigative work is required, but it's not too bad.